# ExtJS container with border layout and dynamic height children

Tags: javascript, layout, extjs, border

I would like to have a container with border layout (I need the split bar) with two regions, west and center.
The west region contains a treepanel that can expand (because it's a treepanel) and I don't know the number of nodes. The center region is also a container that holds a grid and I don't know the number of rows.
So both regions' height is unknown until the page is loaded.
I also want the page to be scrollable in case one of the regions are bigger than the page. I managed to do so when the main container was without border layout and with autoHeight - although I know it's a bad solution.

Any1 has an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Can the two panels scroll independently?  Or do you want the page to scroll only at the highest level?

Comment: I would like the page to scroll at the highest level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`column` layout would do what you want, but it wouldn't give you the split bar.  I think the split bar needs to know the height of what it is splitting, so in order to get this working fully, you may have to add and control your own split bar.