# ExtJS HTML Rendering Incorrectly

Tags: html, css, extjs4

I have the following windowed environment setup with ExtJS.  You can see there is a window border in the top, left corner, another shadow border a little further down and to the right, and finally the actual window towards the bottom right (with the "End Chat" button).  I have confirmed that these three components are part of the same window, but for some reason, they don't render together.  If I resize the browser window, I can get the shadow border to move (because of constraints), but when I drag the actual window (the one of the "End Chat" button) the other two borders don't move at all.  Any ideas?

[image]

```
Ext.define('ipmcc.view.ChatWindow', {
extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
alias: 'widget.ChatWindow',
constructor: function (ChatInteractionModel, index) {
    this.callParent();
    me = this;
    this.chatInteractionModel = ChatInteractionModel;
    this.id = 'Chat_' + ChatInteractionModel.get('interactionUuid');
    this.setTitle(ipmcc.settings.strings.ChatWindowTitle + " - " +  ChatInteractionModel.get('name'));
    this.setPosition(560 + index*50, 30 + index*50);
    this.query("#txtMessageText")[0].focus();
    this.activeChat = true;
},
autoShow:true,  
closable: true,
closeAction: 'hide',
constrain: true,
frame: true,
height: 300,
hidden: true,
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    align: 'stretch',
    pack: 'start'
},
maximizable: true,
padding: 5,
width: 600,
items: [...]
});
```

Comment: Can you give us a working link? It's most likely not a HTML/CSS issue, as ExtJS computes sizes and positions using JavaScript and does not rely on CSS/inheritance/layout too much. Are you using BorderLayout? It's known to cause trouble: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7161889/extjs-container-with-border-layout-and-dynamic-height-children

Comment: @threed EarthBound reference?

Comment: @Sergiu Not using BorderLayout.

Comment: @Eric Sorry, not familiar with EarthBound